# How to use a maybe unallocated target iterator in Python?

Tags: python, iterator

If one would like to run an algorithm on an arbitrary interchangeable data source, it's a good idea to use iterators:

```
def do_something(iter):
    for x in iter:
        print(x)

l = list([1, 2, 3])
do_something(iter(l))
```

In the given example, the iterator is a *source*. But how would it look, if I would like to use the iterator as a *target*? Something like:

```
def do_something(iter, target):
    for x in iter:
        # if x is prime, insert it into target

l = list([1, 2, 3])
primes = ... # something that will be able to take the primes
do_something(iter(l), primes)
```

I could just use `list`'s `append`, but that would not work if the target iterator would not be a list, but some different iterator.

In that example, the target iterator is not even allocated. I also wonder how I could/should preallocate and how it would look using `nditer` and NumPy.

Comment: Are you talking about coroutines? https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/coroutines.html

Comment: `geneator.send(x)`?

Comment: unless you are talking about `do_something` generating values itself, in which case you would probably want just `yield x` so that it is an iterator itself.

Comment: Unlike C++, Python doesn't have output iterators.

Comment: I removed the `numpy` tag since the core of the question isn't about that.  If you want to focus on `np.nditer`, do so in a new question.  It has nothing to do with regular Python iteration or generators.  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html#iterator-allocated-output-arrays

Answer (score 2):

First, just a terminology note: an iterator is a read-only construct; it's an object that has a `next` method. So `target` is not an iterator, but something else.

What you want is something that is guaranteed to have an `append` method, which is any class that inherits from `collections.MutableSequence`. `list` is just one such class, albeit (the only?) one that is part of the standard library.

Python being the dynamically typed language it is, it is not *required* that `target` be an instance of a type that inherits from `MutableSequence`. It is a *sufficient* condition (such an object will work), but it is not a *necessary* condition (an object can have a suitable `append` method without actually inheriting from `MutableSequence`).

So the short answer is: go ahead and use `append`. Just be sure to *document* that the `target` argument must support `append`, and let your users decide what to use.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a generator and use the `.send` method to return values to the `yield` statement:

```
def is_prime(n): #for this demo
    return not any(n%i==0 for i in range(2,n))

def do_something(iter, target):
    for x in iter:
        if is_prime(x):
            target.send(x)

def show_results(message):
    while True:
        x = yield
        print(message, x)

l = range(10)
primes = show_results("this is a prime number:")
next(primes) #need to do this before sending values to a generator
do_something(iter(l), primes)
```

Although you could also just pass a callable as the Target, that way you can either pass `generator.send` or `list.append` as the `target`, or any other function that does something with a single value:

```
def do_something(iter, process_func):
    for x in iter:
        if is_prime(x):
            process_func(x)

l = range(10)
primes = show_results("this is a prime number:")
next(primes) #need to do this before sending values to a generator
do_something(iter(l), primes.send)

#or

primes = []
do_something(iter(l), primes.append)
print(primes)
```